# Optimization of nested join

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm trying to get an order sum for a group of merchants on my website. I have to check for two item types, and this makes the query is terribly slow. This is the (transscribed for readability) query I'm using now

```
SELECT User.ID, COUNT(Order.ID) FROM User
  INNER JOIN UserGroup ON UserGroup.userID = User.ID AND UserGroup.groupID = 4
  LEFT JOIN Meal ON Meal.userID = User.ID
  LEFT JOIN Produce ON Produce.userID = User.ID
  LEFT JOIN Order ON (type = 'Meal' AND typeID = Meal.ID) OR (type = 'Produce' AND typeID = Produce.ID)
WHERE Order.rating > 50 AND Order.status = 'DELIVERED'
ORDER BY User.ID ORDER BY COUNT(Order.ID) DESC
```

Of course all linking and status columns are indexes. When I run an `EXPLAIN` of the query, I can see that it joins the `Order` tabel as `type ALL`, which I'm pretty sure is the problem, I just can't figure out how to make it join as `ref` too. It currently takes 2.74 sec to execute.

(Don't check for typos in this query, I changed table and field names for readability and might have missed something, however all information regarding my question is in.)

**Output of `EXPLAIN`**

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys           | key     | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | UserGroup | ref    | userID,groupID          | groupID | 4       | const            |   74 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | User      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,isDeleted       | PRIMARY | 4       | UserGroup.userID |    1 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Meal      | ref    | userID,isDeleted,status | userID  | 4       | UserGroup.userID |   18 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Produce   | ref    | userID,status,isDeleted | userID  | 4       | User.ID          |   13 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Order     | ALL    | status,isDeleted,type   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 1960 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `EXPLAIN` along with the indices on the `Order` table?

Comment: Often a union ALl query is faster than a queery with an or condition in teh join. I know this is true for SQL Server and I suspect it is true for my sqlas well. OR conditions are to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: @HLGEM is right. You can rewrite it as a union with each part of the ON condition for orders in the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue. I could go two ways:

Using a `UNION` as suggested in the comments above (execution time: ~ 10.5ms)

```
SELECT User.ID, SUM(orderCount) AS totalOrders FROM (
  (
    SELECT User.ID, COUNT(Order.ID) AS orderCount
    FROM User
    INNER JOIN UserGroup ON User.ID = UserGroup.userID AND UserGroup.groupID = 4
    LEFT JOIN Meal ON User.ID = Meal.userID
    LEFT JOIN Order ON Order.type = 'Meal' AND Order.typeID = Meal.ID
    GROUP BY User.ID
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT User.ID, COUNT(Order.ID) AS orderCount
    FROM User
    INNER JOIN UserGroup ON User.ID = UserGroup.userID AND UserGroup.groupID = 4
    LEFT JOIN Produce ON User.ID = Produce.userID
    LEFT JOIN Order ON Order.type = 'Produce' AND Order.typeID = Produce.ID
    GROUP BY User.ID
  )
) AS uni
GROUP BY User.ID
ORDER BY totalOrders DESC
```

Or I could make the `Order` table the primary table and do a `GROUP BY COALESCE()` (execution time: ~76 ms)

```
SELECT COALESCE(Meal.userID,Produce.userID) AS cook, COUNT(Order.ID) AS totalOrders 
FROM Order
LEFT JOIN Meal ON Order.type = 'Meal' AND Order.typeID = Meal.ID
LEFT JOIN Produce ON Order.type = 'Produce' AND Order.typeID = Produce.ID
INNER JOIN UserGroup ON UserGroup.groupID = 4 AND (Meal.userID = UserGroup.userID OR Produce.userID = UserGroup.userID)
GROUP BY cook
HAVING cook IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TotalOrders DESC
```

I decided on the latter one for readability. If someone knows how to fix my the query in the original question please let me know. I'm writing it as part of a larger script where I can quickly join query modifiers. These don't work anymore if I have to change the query this much.